# How to change existing model attribute through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables: invoices and Invoice_Line_Items , invoice has_many Invoice_Line_items. Invoice_Line_Items belongs_to Invoice. Invoice has its foreign key in Invoice_line_items. When I create a new invoice, I choose the different Invoice_line_items and then save. However when I go and check the Invoice_line_item its invoice_id: is nil. It does not update the invoice_id foreign key in each of the Invoice_line_item.

*update*

It is true I am saving the child item before the parent (invoice).

**models**

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :proposal_line_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :suppliers, :through => :proposal_line_items
end


class Proposal_Line_Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :proposal
  belongs_to :supplier
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

**form_for Invoice**

```
<%= form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>
  <% if @invoice.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@invoice.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this invoice from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @invoice.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :fecha_de_expedicion %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :fecha_de_expedicion %>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :invoice_line_item %><br>
    <%= collection_select( :invoice_line_item, :invoice_line_item_id, @invoice_line_items, :id, :supplier_id,  {}, {:multiple => true}) %>
    </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

thank you

Comment: More code would certainly help. But one thing to check is that you're saving the parent (invoice) before trying to save the line_iterms which depend on that value.

Comment: We need to see some code in order to help you.

Comment: Show how are you building **Invoice_line_item** on creating **Invoice**